# Force Activate Windows screen

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-activation

I would like to test a use case for my program. When you have not activated your windows, a blue screen pops up and says that Windows need to be activated (at random times).

[image: Activate Windows Screen]

Is it possible to force this screen to show up (on a non-activated Windows version)? The closest I found is "slui.exe" but that shows the activation wizard but not the full screen that pops up.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @Ramhound - I have a test system that has an non-activated Windows build. I'm asking how I can pop that window up (at the moment it shows up a random times which is not ideal for testing)